# Переинициализация репозитория git

Tags: git, github

Есть ПК - А. Есть ПК - Б. Есть инициализированная папка - FOLDER.
На А есть инициализированный репозиторий.
Требуется разъинициализировать FOLDER на А и перенести на Б, а также инициализировать FOLDER на Б в тот же репозиторий.

p.s.
Купил новый ноутбук, нужно перенести репозиторий на новый со старого, как поэтапно без ошибок сделать это?

Comment: Есть проект `А`, данный проект содержится на ПК - `А1`, в папке C:/Projects/MySuperAProject/
Если в папке MySuperAProject есть папка .git.
То просто перемести папку (MySuperAProject) на другой хард.

Comment: На другой ПК (по идее другой хард) так же легко можно перенести?

Comment: ну да. Как я вижу у вас это еще и на github лежит? Если да, то можно просто сделать clone репозитория.

Comment: Clone сразу иницализирует папку?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял то да

Comment: @BigTows Клонировал. Из-за .gitignore у меня клонировалить только .cpp, .h, .sln. В итоге на новом ноутбуке 580+ ошибок при запуске проекта. (E1696,E0282,E0260,E0020 и еще множество).

Comment: упакуйте любым архиватором каталог с рабочей копией (не пропустив собственно хранилище — подкаталог `.git`), скопируйте и разархивируйте куда требуется. // p.s. «инициализация» — это вообще к делу не относится (т.к. хранилище у вас уже есть и непустое).

Comment: Вообще репозитория и следования инструкций в нём должно быть достаточно, чтобы воспроизвести проект, не имея рабочей копии заранее. Если для вашего репозитория это не работает, это серьёзная организационная проблема, которая проявит себя при расширении круга разработчиков.